# given a metric space, how can I describe converging sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

For instance, let $(\mathbb{N},d)$ be a metric space with $ d(x,y)= \dfrac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$, im asked to describe all convergent subsequences 
for convergent:
we knowt $x_n \to x \iff d(x_n,x) \to 0 \iff |x_n-x| \to 0 \iff x_n \to x$, but how do I "describe" it?

Comment: Note that the elements of the space are integers. Integers can only get so close before they are actually equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show that the sequence needs to be "eventually constant"

Comment: could you elaborate? how do I show that

Comment: @johnny1991: show that for a sequence $x_n$ to converge to $x$, the numerator $x_n$ must converge to $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $|x_n-x| \rightarrow 0$- but that can only happen if $x_n=x$ for some $N$ onwards.

Comment: from the above working have I not shown that $|x_n - x| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ ? is this not saying that for some $n>N$ we have $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$, i don't see how that implies $x_n = x$ for $n>N$

Comment: @johnny1991: because $x_n,x \in \mathbb{N}$, so choose $\epsilon <1$. Two natural numbers, with dist. between them $<$1?

Comment: I see, so $x_n = x$ for some $n \geq \mathbb{N}$ so $x_n$ is eventually constant, but why am I doing this exactly? I mean, from the above working in my first post does this not imply that $x_n = x$ eventually (no need for natural numbers?)

Comment: @johnny1991: If you have proved the third equivalence above, then you are done.

Comment: Am I done? The question asks to describe all convergent sequences - how have I described them exactly? have I just shown that every sequence is convergent in this metric space?

Comment: @johnny1991: By saying that they are eventually constant :)

Comment: OK thank you, could you explain how this would change is we set the metric $(X,d)$ for any set $X$? I believe that will still remain to be a metric

Comment: @johnny1991: This will still remain a metric. In fact this is a standard exercise in functional analysis.

Comment: Yes - but how would we be able to describe all metric sequences? I think the consequence would be all convergent sequences in this metric converge in the usual sense but I'm not sure

Comment: @johnny1991: yes. That's true. That's what the exercise states. See Conway for instance.

Comment: So if that is true for a general set, then why did we show that $x_n$ is eventually constant? are not all convergent sequences eventually constant

Comment: @johnny1991: But all convergent sequences in $\mathbb{N}$ are eventually constant.

Comment: and in general sets they are not?

Comment: @johnny1991: No... for example consider $1/n \in \mathbb{R}$. Converges to $0$, but not eventually const.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my questions, and apologies for my stupidity!